# T-SQL - Several groupings with computation

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, cursor

I need assistance on how I can come up with a query wherein the Table 1 and table 2 will be joined to perform calculation. I have 'cursor' in mind but I am having trouble on conceptualizing. Some kickstart will be a huge help.

basically what I need is something like this:

Table 1:

```
Rep_Date    NumID   NumValue   Score    Period
1/10/2015   1       161        4        Q1
1/11/2015   1       167        2        Q1
1/12/2015   1       95         1        Q1
1/01/2016   1       150        1        Q2
1/02/2016   1       100        2        Q2
1/03/2016   1       600        5        Q2
1/10/2015   38      1          1        Q1
1/11/2015   38      1          2        Q1
1/12/2015   38      1          2        Q1
1/01/2016   38      1          1        Q2
1/02/2016   38      1          2        Q2
1/03/2016   38      1          4        Q2
1/10/2015   113     5          3        Q1
1/11/2015   113     2          4        Q1
1/12/2015   113     8          1        Q1
1/01/2016   113     11         4        Q2
1/02/2016   113     1          5        Q2
1/03/2016   113     5          3        Q2
```

Table 2

```
NumID   CalculationType
1        SUM
38       SUM
113      AVG
```

Expected Result:

```
Rep_Date    NumID   Result  Period
1/10/2015   1       7       Q1
1/01/2016   1       8       Q2
1/10/2015   38      5       Q1
1/01/2016   38      7       Q2
1/10/2015   113     2.67    Q1
1/01/2016   113     4       Q2
```

1. Join by NumID to get the calculation type.
2. Use 'Score' field to derive the result.
3. Group by NumID, Period

Comment: Write a query for the `SUM` calculations and another for the `AVG` calculations. After that you can `UNION` the results and `ORDER BY` appropriately. Since `SUM` and `AVG` return different data types you'll probably need a [`CAST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to get them to agree for your single `Result` column. You could also fiddle about with a [`CASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression to handle either function in a single query. Please add your code to the question if you run into a specific problem.

Comment: Hi @HABO , your solution may not be comprehensive but sure it triggered a kickstart!! Nice! I am still working on my query though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
declare @t1 table (Rep_Date varchar(50), numId int, numValue int, score int, period varchar(50));
insert into @t1 values


('1/10/2015','1','161','4','Q1'),
('1/11/2015','1','167','2','Q1'),
('1/12/2015','1','95','1','Q1'),
('1/01/2016','1','150','1','Q2'),
('1/02/2016','1','100','2','Q2'),
('1/03/2016','1','600','5','Q2'),
('1/10/2015','38','1','1','Q1'),
('1/11/2015','38','1','2','Q1'),
('1/12/2015','38','1','2','Q1'),
('1/01/2016','38','1','1','Q2'),
('1/02/2016','38','1','2','Q2'),
('1/03/2016','38','1','4','Q2'),
('1/10/2015','113','5','3','Q1'),
('1/11/2015','113','2','4','Q1'),
('1/12/2015','113','8','1','Q1'),
('1/01/2016','113','11','4','Q2'),
('1/02/2016','113','1','5','Q2'),
('1/03/2016','113','5','3','Q2');


declare @t2 table (numId int, CalculationType varchar(50));
insert into @t2 values
('1'        ,'SUM'),
('38'       ,'SUM'),
('113'      ,'AVG')

select
   min(t.rep_date) Rep_Date
  ,t.numId
  ,case when max(t2.CalculationType) = 'SUM' then sum(t.score)
        when max(t2.CalculationType) = 'AVG' then round(avg(1.0 * t.score), 2)
        else 0
   end Result
  ,t.period
from
  @t1 t
  join @t2 t2 on t.numId = t2.numId
group by
   t.period, t.numId
order by
  numId, period
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Hi @Slava! Thanks!! Just perfect!!